# EntityType 'MembershipUser' has no key defined. Inherited class

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I'm attempting to add a mirgration before I run my project.

I get the following error when I attempt to add a mirgration

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'MembershipUser' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'MembershipUsers' is based on type 'MembershipUser' that has no keys defined.
```

Here is the class:

```
    <Table("aspnet_Membership")>
Public Class UserMembership
    Inherits User

    Public Property ApplicationId As Guid

    Public Property Comment As String

End Class
```

Its parent:

```
<ReadOnlyAttribute(True), Table("aspnet_Users")>
Public Class User

    <Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), DisplayName("User Id")>
    Public Property UserId As Guid

    <Required, StringLength(256)>
    Public Property UserName As String

    <Required, StringLength(256)>
    Public Property LoweredUserName As String

    <StringLength(16)>
    Public Property MobileAlias As String

    <Required>
    Public Property IsAnonymous As Boolean

    <Required>
    Public Property LastActivityDate As DateTime
End Class
```

Finally OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of MembershipUser)().Map(Sub(m)
                                                 m.MapInheritedProperties()
                                                 m.ToTable("aspnet_Membership")
                                             End Sub)
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The exception talks about `MembershipUser` but your class has the name `UserMembership`. Is this a typo?

Comment: As  Slauma says its a typo, silly me. Thanks  Slauma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The exception talks about MembershipUser but your class has the name UserMembership. Is this a typo?

Comment: But your Fluent mapping uses `MembershipUser`. Did you have two classes: `MembershipUser` AND `UserMembership`? Otherwise I would expect that you got a compile time error. How did you solve the problem now?

Comment: It was referencing System.Web.Security.MembershipUser